# How to fix the same dimension for all my images in react native?

Tags: image, react-native

I want to add an image in my view. This image will change dynamically.
I want them to have the same dimension on my screen.

However, some images look bigger on screen.
Here is my code:

```
image: {
flex: 1,
width: 90,
height: 150,
resizeMode: 'contain',
marginTop: 15 ,
marginBottom: 15,
borderColor: 'white',}
```

The image is inside a view with `flexDirection: row` and `flex:1`

Comment: It is probably due to `resizeMode: 'contain'`. If your image is not the same ratio as the one you defined (90x150), it will max out either the height your the width, than adjust to other in order to fit. That's probably why they do not look the same. Unless you use `stretch` or `cover`, you wont be able to get the same dimension if your image ratio is different.

Comment: test with another `resizeMode` option.

Comment: thanks. Now I can figure out why it doesn't work. I can't change the resizeMode. I'll try anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting both flex and a fixed width/height, one of these properties is overlapping the other, flex tries to dynamically resize the component to fit it's proportion. If you need a fixed size for these images, try taking away the flex property. To check what this property does, and even play a little with it live, check the docs for react native on height and width (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/height-and-width).

If you do need the image to be a fixed size, but also needs it to be in a certain portion of the screen with a certain flex, I'd recommend wrapping it inside a View that has the flex property, so the image itself doesn't change sizes and won't be incorrectly resized.

If this still doesn't give you the behavior you need, your only other option is to change the resizeMode to one more suitable to your needs, check further modes in the docs (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image#resizemode)

Comment: Thanks. It's already wrap in a view with flex 1. I tried removing the image flex property, it's not satisfying.

Comment: @benda if it isn't satisfying and messing with the resizeMode doesn't work for you, you can either fix your image files themselves so they remain the right proportion, or change the Image component width and height dynamically to fit the image file so it never even gets resized. Check the Image method getSize() and see if that works out: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image#getsize

Comment: Thanks. I'll try.